# Replace all domain names in url

Tags: bash, sed, replace

Let's say I have a sitemap file like this:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
       <loc>https://www.sampledomain.com/foo.html</loc>
       <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
       <priority>0.7</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
       <loc>https://www.anotherdomain.nl/hello.html</loc>
       <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
       <priority>0.3</priority>
    </url>
    ...
</urlset>
```

I would like to replace all the URL's (not hardcoded to *www.sampledomain.com* and *www.anotherdomain.nl*) to *www.mynewwebsite.org*, without changing the folder/page paths.

Is this possible using bash?

**Edit:**
Desired output:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
       <loc>https://www.mynewwebsite.org/foo.html</loc>
       <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
       <priority>0.7</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
       <loc>https://www.mynewwebsite.org/hello.html</loc>
       <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
       <priority>0.3</priority>
    </url>
    ...
</urlset>
```

Comment: Can you show an example with input and desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sed command applies the replacement only inside `<loc>` tags:

```
sed 's@<loc>.*www.\w*\.\w*/@<loc>https://www.mynewwebsite.org/@' inputfile
```

In this case, using `@` as sed's delimiter is useful because we don't have to escape slashes. For your input file the following output is produced:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">                             
    <url>                                                                
       <loc>https://www.mynewwebsite.org/foo.html</loc>                           
       <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>                                   
       <priority>0.7</priority>                                          
    </url>                                                               
    <url>                                                                
       <loc>https://www.mynewwebsite.org/hello.html</loc>   
       <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
       <priority>0.3</priority>
    </url>
    ...
</urlset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't what I intended (also not what was asked). I've updated my question with a desired output.

Comment: I'm trying and it don't give the desired output.

Comment: This doesn't produce the expected output nor does it even try to solve the intent of the problem (just change the domain name for any ".html" file and leave the ".html" file name that follows as-is), and yet it's the accepted answer and has multiple up-votes. Go figure...

Comment: @EdMorton, I tested this answer and it produces the desired output posted in the question.

Comment: I also tested it and not only does it not produce the expected output, it simply cannot produce the expected output since it's going to replace every URL, including `https://www.anotherdomain.nl/hello.html`, with `https://www.mynewwebsite.org/foo.html` (note the change from "hello.html" to "foo.html"). Test it again and this time run "diff" rather than just visually inspecting the expected vs actual output.

Comment: @xDantehh please see the corrected command.  As per Ed Morton comment, the command accepted as the answer was not correct so I corrected it and now it gives the desired output.